How to add Microsoft Graph permissions to managed identity service principal using Az PowerShell?
I'm working on connecting to Microsoft Graph using a User Managed Identity (UMI). I've already created the managed identity in the Azure portal, but now I need to assign permissions like User.Read.All and Group.Read.All to this identity using PowerShell to retrieve user and group information.
I previously asked a similar question and got solution using the Microsoft Graph PowerShell module here Grant access to managed identity service principal - Microsoft Graph PowerShell. However, now I need to achieve the same result using the Az PowerShell module.
Here’s the old script using the AzureAD module:

Connect-AzureAD



$TenantID = "TenantID"

$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

$NameOfMSI = "my-managed-identity"

$Permissions = @("Group.Read.All", "User.Read.All")



$MSI = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$NameOfMSI'"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq

'$GraphAppId'"



foreach ($PermissionName in $Permissions) {

    $AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object {

        $_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes

-contains "Application"

    }

    New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId

-PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId

-Id $AppRole.Id

}


Can anyone guide me on how to do this with the Az PowerShell module or is it possible at first?

To add Microsoft Graph permissions to managed identity service principal using Az PowerShell, make use of below sample script:
Connect-AzAccount
$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
$NameOfMSI = "testusermsi"
$Permissions = @("Group.Read.All", "User.Read.All")

$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -AppId $GraphAppId

foreach ($name in $Permissions) {
    $AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRole | Where-Object {
        $_.Value -eq $name -and $_.Origin -contains "Application"
    }

    if ($AppRole) {
        try {
            New-AzADServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment `
                -ServicePrincipalDisplayName $NameOfMSI `
                -ResourceDisplayName $GraphServicePrincipal.DisplayName `
                -AppRoleId $AppRole.Id
        } catch {
            Write-Error "Failed to assign ${name}: $_"
        }
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where permissions added successfully to service principal as below:


Hi sirdevi, in place of graph permissions I want to assign directory readers role to managed identity but New-AzRoleAssignment throws "Cannot find role definition with name 'Directory Readers'" error can you help?

@LS Please post a new question with more details on your requirement by including complete command, error message and share the link here.

Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79222783/cant-assign-directory-readers-role-to-managed-identity-using-az-powershell-ro

@LS Added answer to the new question. Please check and let me know if it works : )

@LS Glad to be of help
